# Navigation Drawer customizado e colorido

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Olá, o que eu queria é fazer era poder colocar ícones coloridos no navigation, como eu posso fazer isso?

As imagens que eu tenho no meu projeto são coloridas mas no navigation elas ficam só acinzentadas assim. Agradeço a ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `onCreate()` da sua `ActivityMain` coloca o código abaixo:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view); // Aqui com certeza você já faz
// A linha abaixo permite você visualizar os icones com outras cores sem ser a cor padrão
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Você irá ver o resultado assim que iniciar a aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu tinha colocado uma linha de código errada e agora corrigi. Isso resolve seu problema?

Comment: Salvou minha vida!!!! Muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Adicione a cor no seu navigation view  que fica em **activity_main.xml**: `app:itemIconTint="@android:color/blue"`

O matiz padrão é preto, mas você pode usar um tom de preto ainda mais escuro usando # 000000

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:itemIconTint="#000000"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

[Traduzido de](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407448/change-color-of-navigation-drawer-icon-in-android-studio-default-template)

Comment: não é bem isso, que queria, eu quero os ícones coloridos